# Store Tags in SQL and Retrieve it

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have a started to learn php & mysql and currently i`m thinking about possibility how to store and retrieve tags for some products.

I would like to assigne tags for specified products and after that display using while method or similiar

At the first step i was thinking to store it in one field, but i have not idea how to retrive it every words as unical item.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_keywords` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_image` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_specification` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_spec_link` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_webstie` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Any ideas ?

I read here that the best way is to create separate table for this purpose and assign them to the specific product ID, but currently i cant imagine it, how it will work when i want to add new tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

After many of research time i think i found the best way to realize my idea.
First we have to do separate table for tags and create relationships with other tables using many to many or one to many option, depends of way which i want to use.
In case of multiple products which will have multiple tags which can be repeated then i have to use relationships many to many.

Please correct me if i made mistake.